# counting coins after a certain time

Tags: unity, c#

I am beginner in unity .
and now i am trying to write my first game.
the game is includes appear random coins in random place on the screen , after passing a certain amount of time.(one coin will be appear and then after for example 2 seconds it will be destroyed and the other coins will be appear in another place ).
there is a  counter  which calculate the  number of click on coins which appear in scene and counting number  of clicks on screen The coin is a prefab .Now i need to count the number of coins that will be disappear after certain amount of time.

can someone help me how i can write the code.

Comment: If you have already a counter variable for the disappearing coins, all you need to do is increase it by one before you destroy it. Since your question does not contain any code, what have you tried and what do you have currently that is causing an error/ problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Sorry if there is problem in my question .In this way that you told me it can count all the coins appear in scene.I want to count the number of coins that without  clicking on coins will be disappear

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to count the number of coins that was not clicked after some period of time, and that you want to destroy them?

If that is the case, then if you have a script `Coin` for example on your prefab. One way to count the remaining coins is by `FindObjectsOfType<Coin>()`. This will return an array objects in the scene that has `Coin` component attached. You can use the `Length` property to get the number of coins and do whatever you need to do with it.

```
var coins = FindObjectsOfType<Coin>();
Debug.log($"Coins left: {coins.Length}");
```

If you want to destroy those coins then you can loop the array.

```
foreach (var coin in coins)
{
    Destroy(coin.gameObject);
}
```

Is this what you're asking for?

Also, just a side note since you're a beginner. At some point in the future you might need to research about the concept of object pooling. This will help a lot in terms of performance if you are instantiating lots of objects in the scene, and making them disappear, and then show again. In pooling, instead of completely destroying the game object, you just disable them and reuse them later. Instantiating lots of objects is expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation .